# Условие для появления кнопки

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет, как то стрельнуло в голову, сделать простейшую тестовую игрулю. Цель - перелистывать картинки нажатием кнопки или ссылки, + при отображении определенной картинки что бы появлялась еще одна кнопка или ссылка для редиректа вообще на другую страницу. То бишь сделать некую вариацию выбора.

Я запихнул все картинки в массив и переключаю их в одном направлении, но не могу поставить условие что бы при отображении определенного элемента массива появлялась кнопка. В html и js я слабоват, и хотелось бы обойтись без jQuery. Подскажите что, да как?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    var index = 0;
    var links = new Array(
      "1.PNG",
      "2.PNG",
      "3.PNG"
    );

    function slide(v) {
      var element = document.getElementById("pic");
      index += 1 * v;
      if (index > links.length - 1) index = 0;

      element.src = links[index];
    }
    $(function() {
      var x = $("#pic").src();
      if (x == "2.PNG") $('#togglee').css({
        display: 'visible'
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#" onclick="slide(1)">Вперед</a>
  <img id="pic" src="1.PNG" style="position:absolute; left:10%; top:20%" />
  <div id="botton">
    <input type="button" id="togglee" value="Togglee" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Если мой ответ Вам помог, то обозначьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый, кликнув на `v` под счетчиком голосов ответа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    var index = 0;
    var links = new Array(
      "1.PNG",
      "2.PNG",
      "3.PNG"
    );

    function slide(v) {
      var element = document.getElementById("pic");
      index += 1 * v;
      if (index > links.length - 1) index = 0;

      element.src = links[index];
      
      document.getElementById("togglee").style.display = (index === 1)? "block" : "none";
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#" onclick="slide(1)">Вперед</a>
  <img id="pic" src="1.PNG" style="position:absolute; left:10%; top:20%" />
  <div id="botton">
    <input type="button" id="togglee" value="Togglee" style="display:none" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```